# CollectionView Button/Image and not refreshing in time issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with some reusability:

```
- (CategoryCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CategoryCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CategoryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.actIn startAnimating];
    cell.cellElementRepresentation = [self.localCategoriesObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell tryToShow]; //this is a important method to my problem

    return cell;
}
```

I commented for you `tryToShow` method. Becouse i think this is a problem. When i scroll to the not visible element in the list I could see "old" elemnts first then new element. Why is that? My `tryToShow` method is basically download manager. I try to describe it in comment. Here is the code:

```
-(void)tryToShow {
    NSString* imageFile = self.linkToImageFileSavedOnDisk //This is my local file saved in documentsDirectory.

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imageFile]) {
        [self.overlayButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFile] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self disableActIn]; //Here i stop and remove activity indicator.
    } else {
        // Here i fire NSURLConnection and try to download. When NSURLConnection finished i put image to overlayButton.
    }
}
```

Here is delegate method:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
     //Here do some stuff to convert Data into UIImage... not important.
     [self.overlayButton setBackgroundImage:object forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

The overlayButton is a button on the `UICollectionViewCell`. I have a custom class for it.

I can't figure it out. How it's possible to image from `indexPath.row` (for example 1) is visible after scroll ? The image is replaced by new one right after new is successfully download, but this is to late.

Comment: You can´t use "dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier" method here, because if you dequeue a cell before getting the request response, when that occurs, you will refresh an incorrect cell. You should use unique identifiers for each cell.

Comment: So what can i use instead `dequeue`?

Comment: Well, in general, to have a better UX, you should cache your cells, so when the user goes down, and then return to the cell, they doesn't need to wait for the request again. So, what i do in those cases, is create a new cell each time, and save the cells in a dictionary where the indexPath is the key, and the cell as value. Then, load the cell from the cache, or create a new one if it's not cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP mention, the problem seems to be that you are setting the `backgroundImage` too late.  So I would try this modifications:

1. First, **clear your cell before setting the new values**. Since you are reusing the cell, the old values (text and images) will still be present in the cell subviews. Setting those values to nil will clear your cell.
2. **Implement a mechanism to validate or invalidate the result from the image request**, since could get the result too late, maybe is no longer needed. Worst, you can set an image no longer correspondent with your data. You should check, before setting a downloaded image, that this image is consistent with the current shown data.
3. **Wait a little before start the image request** If you have a large number of cells, you should think that when the user quickly scroll the collection, you can start lots of requests for images that may never be displayed. I would avoid this behavior by waiting a little before start a new request, and checking if the cell has been reused again.
4. Use the NSURLRequest and configure the cachePolicy attribute as `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`. This will store the responses for the images, there is no need to save the images explicitly save the image and check it's existence.

Comment: Thank you - your answer point me my mistake and solved problem. I will bounty you ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the background image of `self.overlayButton` to nil in the else clause where you start the web request.

```
[self.overlayButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

That way the cell won't appear to have an image loaded already when the user scrolls to it. Or, if it's not loading quickly enough (which it should), you could possibly set the background image to nil in the `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` delegate method instead.

But a problem I see is that you will be creating duplicate `NSURLConnection` objects every time `tryToShow` is called, i.e., the user scrolls down then revisits the cells at the top.

As @lucaslt89 suggested, you could create a dictionary of cells instead of using the default dequeuing. If you do it this way, make sure you have a property for the URL connection object on the cell, and you check for it before starting a new one.

Or, you may want to create a dictionary of any `NSURLConnection` objects you create in the view controller, and move the web request code into the view controller. If a web request is needed, the view controller would check if there was already a web request running in the dictionary first. When the request is finished, the request object would be removed from the dictionary. This would be the desirable method because the cell isn't responsible for creating its own data. In `UICollectionView` the cells have to quickly change roles and it's not wise to associate a particular cell with some data unless there are really few cells.

Either way, you'll avoid creating *multiple* URL requests for the same image.

Hope this helps!